# Can I use my PS3 remote control on my PS4

Tags: ps3, ps4

So I just got a shiny brand new PS4 and it's all exciting. And my PS3 will likely still be around, but it may get relegated to the second room, which means I'd love to be able to use my PS4 for Netflix and the like. **Will my PS3 remote work on my PS4?**

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No, you can not because they are for different consoles.

Comment: This is true.  The PS3 Bluetooth remote is not compatible with the PS4.  As an alternative, you can try the Playstation app for mobile devices, which will sync and give you navigation and playback controls for PS4.

Comment: From personal experience, this is correct.

Comment: Not because they are different consoles (they both have the same features as far as a remote control is concerned), but because Sony want you to buy a new one for each console. Same as the games, controllers, etc. Engineered obsolescence. :)

Answer (score 3):

Sadly the PS3 Media Remote will not work with the PS4.

The PS4 Media Remote, while being "official" and endorsed by Sony, is a very poor substitute for the PS3 version. It does not allow for volume punch-through for an amp, contrary to what the manual says. It could not switch inputs on my SONY amp, which is mind boggling.

Avoid the PS4 Media Remote. You're better off using the included controller.

Answer (score 2):

**No, a PS3 bluetooth remote will not work on the PS4.**

However, in October 2015, a PS4 remote was produced and the functionality is similar to the PS3 remote.

You can find them on [Amazon](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/B00ZJRHSZO) or a number of other shops that carry Sony products.

Comment: The PS4 remote exists, but it is functionally inferior to the old PS3 one.

Answer (score 1):

Yes, download ps4 remote play to your tablet or computer, sync your ps3 controller, and go to your settings on your ps4 to enable remote play and sync your tablet to your ps4 to start using your ps4 with a ps3 controller. It doesn't work with vista, xp, or others, it uses mac or windows 7-8.

Answer (score -1):

You can't but if if you want to use a ps4 remote on a PS3 it will work besides the psn button

Answer (score -1):

No unfortunately, the PS3 Remote additionally works with the PSTV but not the PS4.

Comment: Is this true? Why did it get a downvote?

Answer (score -1):

That's not true what everyone said is wrong you can use the ps43 remotecontrol on the ps4

Comment: Hi kenny, can you provide some kind of evidence to back up your findings?